# Asian Languages Math Advantage

Tags: learning, reference-request, mathematical-ability

I'm looking for a reference showing that asian languages such as Chinese and Japanese allow for easier understanding of numbers than English.

Here's [an excerpt](http://gladwell.com/outliers/rice-paddies-and-math-tests/) from Malcolm Gladwell's "Outliers" that makes the claim:

> The regularity of their number systems also means that Asian children
>   can perform basic functions—like addition—far more easily. Ask an
>   English seven-year-old to add thirty-seven plus twenty two, in her
>   head, and she has to convert the words to numbers (37 + 22). Only then
>   can she do the math: 2 plus 7 is nine and 30 and 20 is 50, which makes
>   59. Ask an Asian child to add three-tens-seven and two tens-two, and then the necessary equation is right there, embedded in the sentence.
>   No number translation is necessary: It’s five-tens nine.
>
> “The Asian system is transparent,” says Karen Fuson, a Northwestern
>   University psychologist, who has done much of the research on
>   Asian-Western differences. “I think that it makes the whole attitude
>   toward math different. Instead of being a rote learning thing, there’s
>   a pattern I can figure out. There is an expectation that I can do
>   this. There is an expectation that it’s sensible. For fractions, we
>   say three fifths. The Chinese is literally, ‘out of five parts, take
>   three.’ That’s telling you conceptually what a fraction is. It’s
>   differentiating the denominator and the numerator.”

Any references on how the effect of these language differences have been studied are appreciated. I've tried searching through Karen Fuson's research, but haven't had any luck yet.